# shopify - nodejs - get permanent token fails

Tags: node.js, authentication, shopify

I have written an application that talks with the `shopify` API. I manage to get the temporary code from shopify and redirect back to my app where I store the code to later exchange for the [permanent token](https://docs.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth#confirming-installation).

According to the docs all I need to do is then send a POST request to `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token` with the `client_id`, `client_secret` and `code` is the body of the request.
I am using the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to send the request and have it set up to send the request as such:

```
var options = {
    method: POST,
    url: https://my-develop-shop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token,
    json: true
  };
var _body = {
    "client_id": config.get('SHOP_ID'),
    "client_secret": config.get('SHOP_SECRET'),
    "code": tempCode
}
_body = JSON.stringify(_body);
options.body = _body;
request(options, callback);
```

However when I send the request it always returns with : `error_description: 'Could not find Shopify API application with api_key ' }`

The app is installed successfully on the client's shop, so why would this error be returned? 
Is there a special header that shopify expects? The docs are so vague.
Why does it not authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Well I cheated and used the [shopify-node-api package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-node-api). There I just use the exchange_temporary_token method. This api also handles throttling so it's a decent investment in the time you might spend incorporating it.

Comment: I have two parts to the project. The part that is giving me trouble is running in a lambda function which is passed the temp code, hence why I am sending a separate request to shopify. It makes no sense though that shopify should complain about the request I am sending it.

Comment: The project I cited is open source so you can check out how he does it.

Comment: I am, I have actually looked at two different modules. All of them send a normal request. Request must be altering something perhaps.

Comment: content type and expect headers.

Comment: Hey @hyprstack were you able to run this on aws lambda? I am facing issues with this package. Everything else works but getAccessToken api doesn't send a response on lambda

Comment: @nats humm.. this was done 5 years ago, but I think I did manage in the end. I'm not sure I still have the code for that project as I've moved on from that company a while back. I would have to do some digging to see what I can find.